# Associated product description not changing on product page

Tags: php, magento

If I change product variation (flavor) on the product page, the product description not changed to the associated product's description. I have checked the configuration and its configured correctly as on the following

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: This is an extension, you should mention this and provide more details about it, the link (if it is free) and the problem you are facing with

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not code related and would be better suited to [Magento StackExchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Robbie Averill - there is no response from the magento stackexchange. so only i posted here

Comment: @laurent the extension we are using is Simple product pricing. The website link is here. In the demo here it is working fine
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-product-pricing.html